# Как динамически навесить/удалить событие для элемента?

Tags: jquery

Есть задача - при скроллировании делать блок невидимым.

```
function closeBox() {
    $('#block').css('display', 'none');
}

$('#block').scroll(function(){
        close();
});
```

Так вот это выглядит неэффективно. При прокрутке страницы постоянно вызывается обработчик.

Можно как-то динамически навесить `scroll(function(){})` на элемент `#block` при отображении (`.css('display', 'block')`) и удалить обработчик после закрытия (`.css('display', 'none')`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй функцию [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

После первого выполнения сразу произойдет снятие обработчика.

```
function closeBox() { $('#block').css('display', 'none'); }

$('#block')).one("scroll", function() {
  close();;
});
```